# c++ or c pow giving wrong result

Tags: c++, math

im trying make my own pow, but i'm getting wrong result

im getting : 2^3.3 = 16, which is wrong... why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double new_pow(double base, double power){

double result = 1;

for(int i = 0; i <= power; i++) {
    result *= base;
}


    return result;
}



int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {

    std::cout << new_pow(2,3.3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me find the bug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignacio's answer already mentions using logarithms. But we ultimately end up using `exp()` which again is a library function. So if you don't want to use library functions at all, then you have to resort to something like [Taylor's expansion](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ey%20taylor%27s%20series&x=0&y=0) of `x^y`

As direct evaluation of Taylor's expansion for `x^y` is tedious, as Ignacio mentioned, `base^power = exp( power*ln(base) )`. And [taylor's expansion for e^x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex%20taylor%20series) is quite simple and that for [ln(x)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%20x%20taylor%20series) is also very simple. Both of them yield for simple interative/recursive  implementation in C

Here is a simple implementation of `e^x` using the above Taylor's expansion

```
double pow_x ( double x , unsigned i )
{
       double prod=1;
       if ( i == 0 )
          return 1;
       while ( i )
       {
             prod*=x;
             i--;
       }
       return prod;
}
             
long long factorial ( unsigned n )
{
     if ( n == 0 )
        return 1;
        
     return n * factorial (n-1);
}

// Function to calculate e^x. Hence expo(5, 20) is calculating
// e^5 by summing 20 terms from the infinite series expansion 
// and NOT a power calculation of 5^20                
double expo ( double x, int terms )
{
       /* terms tells us how long should we expand the taylor's series */
       double sum=0;
       unsigned i=0;
       while ( i< terms )
       {
             sum+= pow_x(x,i)/factorial(i);
             i++;
       }
       return sum;
}
```

`exp(5.93,20)` gives `376.152869` which [Google tends to agree.](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=e%5E5.93&oq=e%5E5.93&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1822l2917l16l3063l4l4l0l0l0l0l290l861l2-3l3l0&gs_l=hp.3...1822l2917l16l3063l4l4l0l0l0l0l290l861l2-3l3l0.frgbld.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=b2927dafcc265fbb&biw=1600&bih=799)

I hope, using this example, you can implement `ln(x)` on your own.

Comment: @user1262876 I agree taylor's expansion is laborious to implement in C/C++. I am working here. Will edit my answer as soon as I find something

Comment: i did: 
inline double log(double x) {
 return x*(1.0 - x*(0.5 - x*(1.0/3.0 - x*(0.25 - x*(0.2 - x/6.0)))));
}
      but it still give wrong, and the pow dosent output the right value...

Comment: You are calculating only till 6 terms. And also, by eyesight, it looks very probable that your equation might have gone wrong. Use a loop as I've done for the exp() function

Comment: Pavan Manjunath, please don't misunderstand me in any wrong way, but could you do the last part, so i can learn from it, you look like a smart man with skills. google says 2^3.2 = 9.18958684, but when i try the pow_x you made it, it says: 2^3.2 = 8

Answer (score 6):

The bug is that your loop runs 4 times, since it won't be more than 3.3 for 4 iterations. This is why floating point exponentiation is implemented with logarithms, not repeated multiplication.

Comment: +1. Only answer which is stating how to solve the problem instead of just pointing out the obvious error!

Comment: so i should use float instead of double?

Comment: No, you should use [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_via_logarithms) instead of iteration.

Comment: log? instead of double or int?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams But I think we still end up `e^(x*ln b )` which still requires exponentiation!

Comment: Have you not heard of `exp()` before?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's not my point. If the OP could use a library function, he could have used `pow()` instead right?

Comment: @Pavan: The asker never claimed to not have access to libm, only that they were "trying make [their] own pow".

Answer (score 0):

Because you are incrementing `i` by 1. so after `4.0`, it will be directly incremented to `5.0`, thus making the condition check of the loop false, and thus terminating the loop.

Also, your starting value for the loop variable is `0`, so you should check it like this -

```
for(double i=0; i<power; i++)
```

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664455/245679) answer to get an idea about how to implement floating point exponentiation and [here](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c) for a pretty high level implementation of it.

Comment: Still wont work! When the powers are floating point numbers, exponentiation cannot be so easily achieved using repeated multiplication

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i <= power; i++)
```

should be

```
for(int i = 1; i <= power; i++)
```

Otherwise, it will run for one extra iteration.

As mentioned in Ignacio Vazquez-Abram's answer.
Assume you want the power y = x^b. 
That is equivalent to ln(y) = b*ln(x).

so `y = exp(b*ln(x))`

```
y = Math.e(b*Math.Log(x)) //Java
```

Comment: You are using `int`...so your `double` is automatically typecasted to `int`....inside your for loop...

Comment: i did change it to double.. before asking.. but still same

Comment: @user1262876 Check Ignacio's answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looping by treating `power` as an `int`. The loop will run 4 times and return `2^4 = 16`.

[How to approximate decimal exponents using logarithms](https://web.archive.org/web/20180704202019/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55580.html).

Comment: @user1262876 You don't have to change it to double. I was simply mentioning why you are getting what you are getting. As Ignacio mentioned, non-integer exponents cannot be done this way. They are done with logarithms.

Comment: so i should use log? float.. im lost

Comment: @user1262876 Check the link in my answer.