# SIMD vectorize atan2 using ARM NEON assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, vectorization, neon, atan2

I want to calculate the magnitude and the angle of 4 points using neon instructions SIMD and arm assembly. There is a built in library in most languages, C++ in my case, which calculates the angle (atan2) but for only one pair of floating point variables (x and y). I would like to exploit SIMD instructions that deal with q registers in order to calculate atan2 for a vector of 4 values.

The accuracy is required not to be high, the speed is more important.

---

I already have a few assembly instructions which calculate the magnitude of 4 floating-point registers, with acceptable accuracy for my application. q1 contains 4 "x" values (x1, x2, x3, x4). q2 contains 4 "y" values (y1, y2, y3, y4). q7 contains the magnitude of the 4 results (x1^2 + y1^2, x2^2 + y2^2, x3^2 + y3^2, x4^2 + y4^2).

```
vmul.f32 q7, q1, q1  
vmla.f32 q7, q2, q2    
vrecpe.f32  q7, q7   
vrsqrte.f32 q7, q7
```

What is the fastest way to calculate an approximate atan2 for two vectors using SIMD instructions?

Answer (score 6):

See [math-neon](http://code.google.com/p/math-neon/source/browse/trunk/math_atan2f.c?r=17) for an existing single valued float implementation.  As it has no (or little) conditionals, it should translate well to an **SIMD** implementation.

As the ARM NEON doesn't have an instruction to calculate this directly, then there are various techniques to create an approximation that are better than a **Taylor series**.  Specifically, the **min-max** approach gives a good polynomial candidate for approximation.  **min-max** refers to minimizing the maximum error; with a [Chebyshev approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory#Chebyshev_approximation) usually being very good.

[DSP guru](http://www.dspguru.com/book/export/html/62) has specifics on different methods for *function approximation*.  There are also numerous books on-line.  You can search for optimum polynomials using *matlab*, *octave* or some other tool-kit.  Typically, you need to bound this with a *range* and *precision*.  Once you have a good algorithm for a single value, extending it to **SIMD** of any sort should be trivial.

The question [calculate atan2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930594/calculate-atan2-without-std-functions-or-c99) has a reference to [Apple's atan.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libm/Libm-315/Source/Intel/atan.c) source.  The co-efficients in code are most likely derived from what I have given above.  The issue with this code is it does not scale to **SIMD** well as the `atan()` approximation is piece-wise and you need different co-efficients depending on the range.  For your **SIMD**, you will need the same co-efficients (multipliers, divisors, equation) through-out the range.

[Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/) has a chapter on *circular functions* with section 4.4.28 giving an logarithmic formulae.  This seems to be the similar to the [*eglibc*](http://www.eglibc.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/libc/sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_atanhf.c?view=markup) implementation.

Comment: I found this website. It is mostly what I'm looking for. I need to change it to neon instructions.  http://www.retro11.de/ouxr/43bsd/usr/src/usr.lib/libm/VAX/atan2.s.html#s:xnot1

Comment: Please see my update, especially the [math-neon](http://code.google.com/p/math-neon/) source.  Section 4.4.48 of **Abramowitz and Stegun** has a good polynomial with the range *-1 to +1*.

Comment: Artless noise, thanks for your answer especially the assembler source. I have some initial questions about the inline assembly in math_atan2f.c. I will visit the chapter that you mentioned and your assembler code to see if I get the answers by myself. I will work on it on Thursday.

Comment: Here are better links to **Abramowitz and Stegun**.  [4.4.28](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_80.htm) [4.4.48](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_81.htm)  The handbook is a very good starting point; it is very difficult to find better polynomials as the book was written at a time (1964) when computing looked quite different and every cycle counted.