# How can i optimize this S-curve function?

Tags: c++, gamma-function

I am working on a gamma function that generates a "S-Curve".
I need to run it in a realtime environment so i need to speed it up as much as possible.

The code is as follows:

```
float Gamma = 2.0f; //Input Variable

float GammaMult = pow(0.5f, 1.0f-Gamma);
if(Input<1.0f && Input>0.0f)
{
    if(Input<0.5f)
    {
        Output = pow(Input,Gamma)*GammaMult;
    }
    else
    {
        Output  = 1.0f-pow(1.0f-Input,Gamma)*GammaMult;
    }
}
else
{
   Output  = Input;
}
```

Is there any way I can optimize this code?

Comment: float Gamma = 2.0f; //Input Variable should be dynamic of course, right?

Comment: its dynamic yes, just setup like this for example purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid [pipeline stalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(computing)) by eliminating branching on `Input<1.0f && Input>0.0f` if the instruction set supports [saturation arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) or use max/min intrinsics, e.g. [x86 MAXSS](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MAXSS.html)

You should also eliminate the other branching via rounding the saturated `Input`. Full algorithm:

```
float GammaMult = pow(0.5f, 1.0f-Gamma);
Input = saturate(Input); // saturate via assembly or intrinsics
// Input is now in [0, 1]
Rounded = round(Input); // round via assembly or intrinsics
Coeff = 1 - 2 * Rounded
Output = Rounded + Coeff * pow(Rounded + Coeff * Input,Gamma)*GammaMult;
```

Rounding should be done [via asm/intrinsics as well](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_110.html).

If you use this function on e.g. successive values of an array you should consider vectorising it if the target architecture supports SIMD.

Comment: What is the advantage of rounding here? The original code doesn't appear to want the result rounded to an integer, and you're not eking out any more performance by avoiding floating-point ops in favor of integer ops as long as you use the `FRNDINT` instruction since that leaves the result on the floating point stack.

Comment: @CodyGray rounding is used to generate the coefficients so that he won't need to branch on `Input < 0.5`. E.g.: `Coeff = 1 - 2 * Rounded` will be 1 if `Input < 0.5` and -1 if `Input > 0.5`, thus what was a branch in the original algorithm now becomes one round instruction, one floating point multiple and one floating point add --> pipelining won't suffer.

Comment: Oh, of course! Very clever. I had missed that in my cursory reading.

Comment: SIMDed `pow` is not very ubiquitous outside of high end compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. The bottleneck, if exists, is the `pow` function. The only solution is to go a bit deeper into low-level details and try to implement your own `pow` function. For example if 2 float digits are sufficient for you, you may found some approximation-based algorithms which are faster.

See this: [The most efficient way of implementing pow() function in floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664445/the-most-efficient-way-of-implementing-pow-function-in-floating-point)

Comment: Another good reference for implementing a custom optimized pow function is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16782797