# function for power of double without math.h

Tags: c, double, pow

I would like to know how to make a function with doubles for power without math.h

for example if I want

```
4.3^2.5
```

Comment: Define your own function for finding  power of double. find out How predefined pow() is working and analyse.

Comment: I'm sure there are a few algorithms available to do it. What have you tried? How did your attempt work? Or not work? Perhaps you should take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Perhaps you need to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The most efficient way of implementing pow() function in floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664445/the-most-efficient-way-of-implementing-pow-function-in-floating-point)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough outline.

`pow(x, y)` is mathematically equivalent to `exp(log(x)*y)` except for issues with domains and special cases. `log(x)` and `exp(x)` can be approximated with series.

Taylor series can be computed from scratch. Advanced implementations use variants of minimax polynomials engineered in advance for specific situations.

Usually, when calculating `log`, we separate the exponent part of the argument from the fraction part, then use a polynomial to approximate the logarithm, then add the logarithm for the exponent part.

When calculating `exp`, we separate the integer and fraction parts and multiply the `exp` of each of them.

With floating-point that uses base two, base-two logarithm and exponentiation are commonly used. Then the logarithm for the exponent *e* (representing 2<sup>*e*</sup>) is simply *e*.

Since, when doing this, you want to manipulate the exponent and significand parts of floating-point values, you have to access their encodings. `math.h` provides routines like `frexp` and `ldexp` for this. To do it without `math.h`, you need to access the bytes of the objects, which is a topic for another Stack Overflow question.

Creating a roughly correct version of `pow` is not hard. Calculating the errors and proving bounds on them takes a fair amount of work, and engineering the polynomials and other calculations to reduce the errors is, in general, difficult.